# Having problems enabling have_ssl mariadb

Tags: ssl, redhat, mariadb

I'm a bit of a unix newbie and am working with a MariaDB Enterprise server on a RHEL 7.2, and connecting to it via a RHEL 7.2 client. I used [this guide](http://xmodulo.com/enable-ssl-mysql-server-client.html) to create all the certificates and keys I need for server and client alike, here's what my.cnf looks like:

```
# Example mysql config file.
# You can copy this to one of:
# /etc/my.cnf to set global options,
# /mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to get server specific options or
# ~/my.cnf for user specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run the program with --help to get a list of available options

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
[client]
#password=my_password
#port=3306
#socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
#datadir=/var/lib/mysql


# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
#port=3306
#socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

temp-pool

# The following three entries caused mysqld 10.0.1-MariaDB (and possibly other versions) to abort...
# skip-locking
# set-variable  = key_buffer=16M
# set-variable  = thread_cache=4

loose-innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:1000M
loose-mutex-deadlock-detector
gdb

######### Fix the two following paths

# Where you want to have your database
data=/var/lib/mysql

# Where you have your mysql/MariaDB source + sql/share/english
#language=/path/to/src/dir/sql/share/english
#language=/usr/local/mysql/share

[mysqldump]
quick
set-variable = max_allowed_packet=16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[myisamchk]
set-variable= key_buffer=128M

[mysqld]
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql-ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql-ssl/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql-ssl/server-key.pem
bind-address=*
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
user=mysql
bind-address=*

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

and I stopped the mysql service and started it like this:

```
service mysql start --ssl-ca=ca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=server-cert.pem --ssl-key=server-key.pem
```

But still, when I try to check if SSL is enabled I always see this:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'have_%ssl';
+---------------+----------+
| Variable_name | Value    |
+---------------+----------+
| have_openssl  | YES      |
| have_ssl      | DISABLED |
+---------------+----------+
```

And the ssl-requiring user I created gets access denied.

According to all the websites I looked up, it's supposed to be enough to just start the mysql service with these ssl details or just the ssl key but nothing works.

What do I do?

Comment: There is no `?` in this question post.  What is your question?  See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "What do I do?" does not add any value.  After the explanation of your situation, ask a very specific question. Please see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I really think I gave enough information. I'm sorry that you can't understand that I can't enable the use of ssl connections in my MariaDB, not from the text and not from the headline.

Comment: Yes you did give plenty of information. Since this is a first post it comes thru the [first post review queue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues), it is going to get extra scrutiny on asking format and style, not only information.  Especially with a longer post, summarization is helpful and needed, either in the title or a simple summary question at the end of post. See the [bad vs good titles](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the guides.

Comment: Check [Enabling SSL in MariaDB running on Synology NAS](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/142252/enabling-ssl-in-mariadb-running-on-synology-nas).

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that every users have read access to your credential files? 
If not, a `chmod ugo+r /etc/mysql-ssl/*` may help.

Comment: I can confirm that this was the problem on Debian. If mysqld can't read one or more of the certificate files it will simple keep the have_ssl variable set to DISABLED. As soon as I fixed my permissions it went from DISABLED to YES.

Comment: I followed this https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-setup-mariadb-ssl-and-secure-connections-from-clients/ tutorial, and this was the missing step to get it running.